Android studio Smooth inflate
I have my own application that I programmed using java in Android studio
The application connects to my server and the server returns json data
The application takes this information, transforms it, and adds it to...
LinearLayout
It may be android:orientation="horizontal"
or
android:orientation="vertical"
Use okHTTP
I am connected to my server, but what I notice is that when I connect, my application becomes lag heavy
And when inflate Layout like
View singlechannel = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.channel, null, false);

The application becomes inoperable unless the period for adding items expires
Please see the problem I have to understand me
https://youtu.be/EouuWjnEmUQ?si=NsIBgMswG8oim_uI
my Scripts
MainActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLiveMatch();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}


public void getLiveMatch(){

        try {
            JSONObject channels = new JSONObject(new HomeClass.getHomeClass().execute(host + "/apiv2/matchlivenow/").get());
            JSONArray js = channels.getJSONArray("data");
            //      Remove PlaceHolder
//            homeMatchLiveLinearLayout.removeAllViews();


            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                int x = i;
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        homeMatchLiveLinearLayout.getChildAt(x).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,i*1000);
            }



            ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout = new  ShimmerFrameLayout(this);
            for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {
                int x = i;
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = js.getJSONObject(x);
                            View singlematchlivenow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.singlematchlivenow, null, false);


                            TextView singlematchlivenowfirst = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowfirst);
                            TextView singlematchlivenowsecond = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowsecond);



                            TextView singlematchlivenowfirstgool = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowfirstgool);
                            TextView singlematchlivenowsecondgool = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowsecondgool);

                            TextView singlematchlivenowchannel = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowchannel);



                            ImageView singlematchlivenowbgimg = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowbgimg);
                            ImageView singlematchlivenowfirstimg = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowfirstimg);
                            ImageView singlematchlivenowsecondimg = singlematchlivenow.findViewById(R.id.singlematchlivenowsecondimg);



                            singlematchlivenowfirst.setText(data.getString("first"));
                            singlematchlivenowsecond.setText(data.getString("second"));
                            singlematchlivenowfirstgool.setText(data.getString("firstgool"));
                            singlematchlivenowsecondgool.setText(data.getString("secondgool"));
                            singlematchlivenowchannel.setText(data.getString("channel"));

                            downloadHomeImage(data.getString("firstimg"), singlematchlivenowfirstimg, shimmerFrameLayout);
                            downloadHomeImage(data.getString("secondimg"), singlematchlivenowsecondimg, shimmerFrameLayout);
                            downloadHomeImage(data.getString("bgimg"), singlematchlivenowbgimg, shimmerFrameLayout);



                            homeMatchLiveLinearLayout.addView(singlematchlivenow);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, x*100);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

HomeClass.java

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HomeClass {
    String host = "http://example.com/json";
    public static class getHomeClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        Response response;
        String cookie = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... String) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            String url = String[0];

            if (String.length == 2)
            {
                cookie = String[1];
                Log.d("COOKIE2",cookie);

            }

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)

                    .header("Cookie", cookie)
                    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0")



                    .build();

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

}




Is there a way to add items easily without any lag here?
In my application, because I notice that applications add items easily without delay or lag in the application
